# How to print out a datetime stamp info in a plpgSQL using "raise info" function for debugging purpose in Redshift environment

Tags: timestamp, amazon-redshift, plpgsql, dbeaver

In T-SQL, one can use the following statement to debug a script --
Print 'variable1 = ' + cast(getdate() as varchar).

How to do the same thing in a plpgSQL in a redshift environment? I am using DBeaver as my sql IDE. I tried the following --
raise info 'variable1 = %', getdate()
and it did not work. Any ideas, please?

raise info 'time now is %', getdate();

raise info 'time now is %', timestamp;

Comment: current_timestamp not just timestamp

Comment: Redshift is based on very old Postgres. Maybe you should to assign value to variable, and then print variable. Old Postgres didn't supported expressions in RAISE statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
t :=current_timestamp;
raise info 'time now is %', t ;
```

The above code works; but I am wondering how to print a timestamp without using a variable in the "raise info" line

Comment: Redshift is based on very old PostgreSQL - maybe 7.4 or 8.0 (2005), and there are lot of features from modern Postgres  not available.